# Contentful - How to change the field value from the React/Node.js environment?

Tags: reactjs, contentful, contentful-management

Is there any way to change the value of some fields in a **Content Type** on a specific **Entry** from an React application. I want to simulate the **like/dislike button**. So when the user clicks the button, I want to change the specific value in the CMS on a specific **Entry**.

Is there a way, for example, to make a POST request to a `Contentful API`, in the React. Or to be precise since I am making API calls from **Node.js** environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leverage the Contentful management API for that. [Here's an example showing how to up a `title` field](https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/references/content-management-api/#/reference/entries/entry/create-update-an-entry/console/js).

```
client.getSpace('<space_id>')
.then((space) => space.getEnvironment('<environment-id>'))
.then((environment) => environment.getEntry('<entry_id>'))
.then((entry) => {
  entry.fields.title['en-US'] = 'New entry title'
  return entry.update()
})
.then((entry) => console.log(`Entry ${entry.sys.id} updated.`))
.catch(console.error)
```

To write data to Contentful you have to create a token with `WRITE` permission. Usually, people create a personal access token for that in the API keys section.

**⚠️ But make sure to not leak your personal access token**. This token has the same access rights as the logged-in user creating it. This means, that you shouldn't use a personal access token with `WRITE` permissions in a React application. People could find it and take over your space.

If your React application is talking to a Node.js backend that you control, that's safe.